# Can Apache Flink achieve end-to-end-exactly-once with built-in connectors in Table-API/SQL?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

i want to know, if Apache Flink (v1.11) can achieve **end-to-end-exactly-once** semantic **with the built-in connectors** (Kafka, JDBC, File) **using Table-API/SQL**?

I can't find anything regarding this in the documentation. Only that i can enable Checkpointing in EXACTLY_ONCE Mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on exactly which connectors you use/combine on the source/sink side.

**Source**

- Kafka supports exactly-once
- Filesystem supports exactly-once
- JDBC is not available as a streaming source yet. Checkout [2] if that's your requirement.

**Sink**

- Kafka supports at-least-once (Flink 1.11) and exactly-once (Flink 1.12) [1]
- Filesystem supports exactly-once.
- JDBC supports exactly-once if the table has a primary key by performing upserts in the database. Otherwise at-least-once.

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/kafka.html#consistency-guarantees

[2] https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. 

So i can only consume a JDBC Table as Source in BatchMode like
`EnvironmentSettings
 .newInstance()
 .useBlinkPlanner()
         .inBatchMode().build()`

And by using the CDC-based connecters from Ververica, i can use it in `.inStreamingMode()`, but than i will catch only the changes but not the initial data in the database, rigtht?

Comment: During a fresh state (no savepoint/snapshot/recovery) the CDC connector will also emit all existing rows before changes.

Comment: Oh, that's nice Thank you very much and keep going with this great framework.

Comment: Configurable via connector option "debzium.snapshot-mode", I believe. https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors/wiki/Postgres-CDC-Connector#connector-options